# How to query Django objects based on a field value in the latest ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application to store hourly price and volume (OHLCV candle) for several markets. What I'm trying to achieve is to compare the latest volume of all markets and set `top10 = True` to the 10 markets with the highest volume in the latest candle. What is the most efficient way to do that ?

EDIT: The queryset should select all the most recent candle in every markets and sort them by volume. Then return the 10 markets the top 10 candles belong to.

**models.py**

```
class Market(models.Model):
    top10 = JSONField(null=True)


class Candle(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candle', null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    volume = models.FloatField(null=True)
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out the solution, I guess.

```
latest_distinct = Candle.objects.order_by('market__pk', '-dt').distinct('market__pk')
candle_top = Candle.objects.filter(id__in=latest_distinct).order_by('-volume')[:10]

for item in candle_top:
    item.market.top10 = True
    item.market.save()
```

`latest_distinct = Candle.objects.order_by('market__pk', '-dt').distinct('market__pk')` will select latest candle record for every `Market`.
`candle_top = Candle.objects.filter(id__in=latest_distinct).order_by('-volume')[:10]` will sort items in previous query in descending order and slice 10 greatest ones.
Then you iterate over it setting each `market.top10` to `True`

Notice that I'm assuming that `Market`'s `top10` field is a boolean. You can substitute your own logic instead of `item.market.top10 = True`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion but this doesn't filter the latest candle of every markets. What I would like to do is sort candle by volume but only the latest candles of all markets.

Comment: Could you please tell me which database you use?

Comment: Sure, I use PostgreSQL

Comment: I have found a solution by creating a list of lists with latest volume and candle primary key.

Comment: I guess I've found quite nice solution. I've tested it in a small django project. Please check if it suits you and let me know.

Comment: It's more flexible than my latest try, thank you! Just notice that it's slower

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my own question by selecting the last candle in every markets with it primary key, and creating a list of lists with list element as `[volume, pk]`. Then I sort the nested lists by list element 0 `volume` and select top 10. It returns a list of desired markets:

```
import operator
v = [[m.candle.first().volume, m.candle.first().id] for m in Market.objects.all()]
top = sorted(v, key=operator.itemgetter(0))[-10:]
[Candle.objects.get(id=i).market for i in [t[1] for t in top]]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your way does not always select the latest ones, because you are calling `.first()` on `m.candle` which may not be sorted by 'dt'

Comment: According to the documentation `first()` sort the queryset by primary keys, which are in chronological order. But I might be wrong